# tvOS UITextField blank after editing

Tags: uitextfield, tvos, tvos9.1

Editing `UITextField` in tvOS shows a new view where the user can enter in text, and when text entry is done, the user is returned to the previous view. However, I have found that when I return from the text editor, the text I edit does not show up in my text fields. What's going on?

tvOS version 9.1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working is because the `UITextField` is using a non-default background color. Apparently in tvOS, the background color is rendered to the layer *after* the text has been rendered (Interestingly enough, this does not affect placeholder text). This also happens in interface builder. A bug report has been sent to Apple.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with shared iOS/tvOS code where the next textfield placeholder text disappeared and became unresponsive.
Make sure that you are NOT setting `textField.endEditing(true)`