# tvOS: Change UITextField text color

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit, tvos, tvos9.1

I'm having issues changing the text color on a UITextField on tvOS.

I've tried setting the color attribute in IB as well as pragmatically setting `textField.textColor = .whiteColor()`

Neither worked.
Potentially something apple disabled in tvOS? Because of the focus engine?

Not sure. I'm completely befuddled

Comment: Its a bug in TVOS rdar://24314619

Comment: The answer in the following thread explains this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34456205/2744264